# Error Accessing Zend Server Web-Interface, "gui directive not found: zend"

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-studio, zend-server

I have a problem with Zend Server (2019.0.4). When I try to access the web-based interface it gives me HTTP 500. The exact error in the php.log file is this:

```
 [07-Jan-2022 18:49:12 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ZendServer\Exception: gui directive not found: zend in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\gui\module\Application\Module.php:166
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\gui\module\Application\src\Application\Db\AbstractFactoryConnector.php(36): Application\Module::config('zend')
#1 C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\gui\module\Application\src\Application\Db\AbstractFactoryConnector.php(30): Application\Db\AbstractFactoryConnector->init()
#2 C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\gui\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\Factory\InvokableFactory.php(30): Application\Db\AbstractFactoryConnector->__construct()
#3 C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\gui\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(769): Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory->__invoke(Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager), 'Application\\Db\\...', NULL)
#4 C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\gui\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(205): Zend\Servi in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\gui\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php on line 776
```

The weird part is that I have had a project up and running on a Zend Server already that's been around and working for over a year now, which I've obviously accessed the web-interface for before. I can still run that project locally just fine so I know the server is running but I cannot access the web interface (at http://localhost:10081/ZendServer/) to setup an additional project! Does anyone know what this error is about and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the answer turned out to be one of my Zend config files was corrupted. That file was the ZendGlobalDirectives file, replacing it with a co-workers copy fixed the issue for me.

Hope this points anyone else having this problem in the right direction